# Bundled Java-Application is recognized as 32-Bit, will it run under macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: java, 64-bit, bundle, macos-catalina

I write and deploy an Application that is written in Java, then compiled and bundled into an application Bundle. The application is then run only internally to my company. So far, no machines run macOS 10.15, but new ones will come soon and thus the application needs to be ready.

When I take a look into the list of installed software, it tells my application is not a 64-Bit application, although it is a Java-application and Java is 64-Bit indeed.

Is there any flags to be set somewhere (e.g. in `info.plist`), to tell the OS to launch/treat it as a 64-Bit application? Or is the whole solved once the application gets signed/notarized by apple? (another thing that I skipped so far)

Comment: How are you checking 32/64 bit application?

Comment: MacOS itself offers this functionality, (About this mac --> Software..) apparently it does not recognize it properly since the result is different on macOS 10.10 and 10.14.

Answer (score 0):

As I have got some never Hardware running 10.14 Mojave and the Java-Application still runs smoothly. Therefore I suppose that it is simply falsely recognized as 32-Bit application by the older operating systems.